# Почему не работает update в room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, room

> Код функции

```
fun updateCurrentNote(view : View){
    compDispose.add(
        Single.fromCallable {
            dataNote.let {data->
                when(data){
                    is BasicNote ->{
                        val updateNote = BasicNote(0,headName!!,bodyText!!)
                        repository.updateBasicNote(updateNote)
                    }
                    is PrivateNote ->{

                    }
                }
            }
        }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe({
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            },{Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"${it.cause}}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()})
    )
}
```

> Toast выводит "succes". Но данные в базе остаются неизменными.

```
@Entity(tableName = "basic_notes")
data class BasicNote(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id : Int,
var header : String,
var body : String) : Notes()
```

> Пожалуйста, объясните, подробно ,где проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обновить запись в БД её надо идентифицировать по ID. Вы же передаёте в качестве ID `0`, невалидный ID, т.к. `ID` должны быть `>=1`.

Вам надо указать конкретный ID, наверное, он у вас в переменной `data` есть.